# Sup-multiplicative function related to sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, sums-of-squares

Say that a representation $n=a^2+b^2$ (where $n,a,b$ are integers)
is normalized if $0\leq a \leq b$.  Among those normalized representations,
there is a unique one minimizing $a$ (or equivalently maximizing $b$) ;
we call it the canonical representation of $n$ (when it exists), and
we denote it by $n=x(n)^2+y(n)^2$.

It is true that $y$ is sup-multiplicative, i.e.

$$
y(nm)\geq y(n)y(m) \tag{1}
$$

whenever $y(n)$ and $y(m)$ exist ? I have checked with a computer that
(1) holds for $0\leq n,m \leq 1000$.

Comment: Is it clear that whenever $y(n),y(m)$ exist $y(nm)$ exists too?

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes, because of the formula $(a^2+b^2)(u^2+v^2)=(av-bu)^2+(au+bv)^2$. $y(n)$ exists iff $n$ is representable as a sum of two squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $0 \leq u \leq v,$ then $m = x^2 + y^2$ and $n = u^2 + v^2,$ we get your inequality from
$$ mn = |xv - yu|^2 + (xu + yv)^2, $$ and
$$ xu + yv \geq yv $$